# If automatic community wiki conversion is gone, why do the confusing messages still exist?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, revisions-list

Now that posts [can't be automatically converted to community wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/), it makes sense to just ditch all those annoying messages for "why" a post got converted in the first place. The code for selecting the message that gets displayed there has always been buggy and inaccurate. In many cases, the reason put there is not at all indicative of what actually happened.

Worse, new cases of community wiki conversion done manually still use that code. I just [converted this question to community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11311672/revisions), and the revision history says:

> Post Made Community Wiki by being **edited by more than 5 different editor**

<sup>(Side note "5 different editor" instead of "...editors" is exact quote of the system message.)</sup>

Well, no, considering auto-conversion no longer exists, it doesn't even make sense to *show* that message on any post after that feature was removed.

It doesn't really make sense to *fix* this code since auto-conversion is gone. But since so many of these messages are so inaccurate, doesn't it make sense to just abandon the messages altogether? **Why not ditch that code and just show the user who caused the conversion to take place in all cases?**

Comment: A few screenshots would make this post easier to parse. Don't forget the freehand red circles...

Comment: what you describe looks like a [meta-tag:bug] doesn't it? Post was made CW by moderator but message says otherwise, that it was because of editors

Comment: @gnat It is, and they've known about it for a long time. But fixing a bug for something that is no longer used seems kind of pointless. It makes more sense to just get rid of the messages altogether.

Comment: you mean, getting rid of it means "ditch that code and just show the user who caused the conversion"? that way, [meta-tag:feature-request] tag makes better sense than "bug", I see