# Help me count editors of this post (made CW by "more than 5 different editor", I found only 3)

Tags: support, edits, specific-question, community-wiki

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/165773) was made community wiki in rev 14. [Edit summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/192046/14) says:

> [**Post Made Community Wiki** by being edited by more than 5 different editor]

<sup>(Side note "5 different editor" (instead of "...editors") is exact quote, that's just the way how system wrote it. Also worth noting that this happened before [removal of automatic CW conversion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773).)</sup>

The problem is, I found only three editors, not five: **Jimmy** edited [rev 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/192046/4), **David** edited [rev 6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/192046/6) and all the rest seems to be done by **yours truly**. (For the sake of completeness, I found fourth editor but it was [after rev 14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/192046/15).)

In a simpler case I would say it's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but here, I am not certain. Revision history [spans three pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/192046/revisions) and I could have missed something.

Were there indeed five different editors when this post was made community wiki?

Comment: I suspect all the bounty notices have something to do with this..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see. 10 bounties, each dropping 4 notices make it 40 entries in revisions history... you seem to have a point here

Comment: Does it matter? That mechanism doesn't exist anymore, so even if it is a bug it can't be triggered now.

Comment: @MadScientist if the CW was triggered incorrectly, I will ask moderator to remove it. Otherwise, I will let it be. Fair enough?

Comment: As for the misspelling, that appears to be a temporary glitch that existed only for a short time period. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/179147/revisions) is the only other use of the phrase I can find with our friend Google. There were clearly 5 other authors before a 6th author triggered the change (other than the OP!).

Comment: As such, it could be that the same revision of the SE stack used the wrong message there and it is simply the *more than 10 edits by you* conversion.

Comment: Related fix-it: [If automatic community wiki conversion is gone, why do the confusing messages still exist?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237200/if-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-is-gone-why-do-the-confusing-messages-st)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think happened:

- You edited that post an additional 11 times after the initial revision. That is enough grounds to convert to Community Wiki (more than 10 edits by the same author).

  You can count them; apart from revision 1 (your initial post), revision 14 is you 11th edit of the post.
- The revision of the Stack Exchange software used botched CW conversion messages; it used the wrong message here *and* that message is misspelled. There is only [one other post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/179147/revisions) that uses that message, but that post was converted to CW because an additional 6 people edited the post (*more than 5 different editors*).

Comment: I checked revisions details and you're right, rev 14 was where it went over the limit of [changes that qualify for CW (body edits)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62673/165773). You know, that seems to make my question a duplicate (there is a side issue of buggy message in revisions history but now that the very feature has gone, [it doesn't matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184207/165773 "'problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete...'"))