# Text accompanying CW-ification in revision history sometimes suggests automatic CW-ification

Tags: bug, community-wiki, revisions-list

I likely don't go through revision histories as much as I should, but I recently came across the following entry that had me scratching my head:

[image: Post Made Community Wiki by question having more than 30 answers]

But wait! [Automatic Community Wiki conversions have been disabled for a while!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) Surely something must be off! But what? Has automatic CW-ification been reinstated?

Thankfully, no. A moderator had actually performed this action, and looking through the moderator tools eventually gave the "culprit":

[image: post flag history]

However, without access to these tools a user might be lead to believe that automatic CW-ification still happens. (I suspect that the revision history text is like this because there was an open "too many recent answers" flag on the post at the time of conversion. Other times the moderator's name is explicitly mentioned in the revision history.)

I'd prefer it if the revision history text simply stated

> **Post Made Community Wiki** by `[User Name]`

whenever a post is CW-ified by a moderator, regardless of the surrounding circumstances. At the very least, the CW-ifying moderator's name should always appear, and so something like

> **Post Made Community Wiki** by `[User Name]` for `[reason]`

would also be fine, should the surrounding circumstances be deemed important to keep in the revision history.

<sub>(The moderator timeline of a post has a similar issue. Though I guess we can see how *this* goes before bringing *that* up.)</sub>

Comment: Related: [If automatic community wiki conversion is gone, why do the confusing messages still exist?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237200/if-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-is-gone-why-do-the-confusing-messages-st)